# Docker nginx image optional tls option

Tags: docker, certificate, environment-variables, nginx

I need to create a nginx docker image, which can be used to configure optional TLS/SSL certificates.

When no certificate is provided, nginx should work as reverse proxy on port 80 and do its job. If a certificate is set, nginx should listen on port 80, redirect to https/port 443 and does its job as reverse proxy.

Is there some "out-of-the-box" solution for that?

The environment variable parsing/template stuff is very simple and dont allow any logic like "if" blocks.

I thought about something like a template engine/syntax like "mustache" or similar to create the server blocks.

Default nginx config:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost ${NGINX_HOSTNAME};

    # remove server version
    server_tokens off;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    autoindex off;    
    access_log off;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location ~ /(api|auth)/(.*)$ {
        resolver ${RESOLVER};
        proxy_pass ${BACKEND_PROTOCOL}://${BACKEND_HOST}:${BACKEND_PORT}/$1/$2;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        index index.html;
    }

}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.23.2-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NGINX_HOSTNAME="example.com"
ENV BACKEND_PROTOCOL="http"
ENV BACKEND_HOST="127.0.0.1"
ENV BACKEND_PORT="8080"
ENV RESOLVER="127.0.0.11"

ARG version=unknown
LABEL version=$version

ARG buildDate=unknown
LABEL buildDate=$buildDate

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template
COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN apk --no-cache add openssl
```

I could do the templating stuff while building the image, the problem with that is, i dont know who uses the image and need that TLS stuff or not. So when no Certificate is provided, nginx does not start because it cant find that file.

The dynamic configuration needs to be create when the container is started.

Has anyone a idea/solution for that?
I cant believe that i am the only one with this issue.